# How to create the sum of a column with LIKE statement in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a sql table as follows,

```
select * from Daily_Usage;

+------------+-------------------+-------------+
| Date       | Provider          | Total_Usage |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
| 2022-01-11 | X1_IC_03          |       22.62 |
| 2022-01-11 | X1_IC_04          |       24.81 |
| 2022-01-11 | X1_IC_05          |       23.90 |
| 2022-01-11 | X2_IC_1           |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X3_08             |       16.86 |
| 2022-01-11 | X4_IC_01          |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X4_IC_02          |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X5_IC_02          |        6.66 |
| 2022-01-11 | X6_12             |       38.66 |
| 2022-01-11 | X6_13             |       25.27 |
| 2022-01-11 | X6_14             |     3205.78 |
| 2022-01-11 | X7_03             |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X8_05             |       11.32 |
| 2022-01-11 | X8_06             |        6.83 |
| 2022-01-11 | X8_07             |        0.53 |
| 2022-01-11 | X8_08             |        0.18 |
| 2022-01-11 | X8_09             |        0.98 |
| 2022-01-11 | X9_IC_03          |         0.00|
| 2022-01-11 | X10_01            |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X11_IC_07         |        0.11 |
| 2022-01-11 | X12_01            |     3178.98 |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let's take `X1_IC_03` first,

In `X1_IC_03` the main provider is `X1` and it might contain anything in right side with `X1`, like `X1%`.So I need to get the sum of `Total_Usage`of all X1 values. So my output is as follows,

```
select * from Daily_Usage;

+------------+-------------------+-------------+
| Date       | Provider          | Total_Usage |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
| 2022-01-11 | X1                |       71.33 |
| 2022-01-11 | X2                |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X3                |       16.86 |
| 2022-01-11 | X4                |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X5                |        6.66 |
| 2022-01-11 | X6                |      3269.71|
| 2022-01-11 | X7                |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X8                |       19.84 |
| 2022-01-11 | X9                |         0.00|
| 2022-01-11 | X10               |        0.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | X11               |        0.11 |
| 2022-01-11 | X12               |     3178.98 |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am going to get this output by using following query,

```
select 
    Date, Provider, sum(Total_Usage) 
from 
    Daily_Usage 
where 
    Provider like 'X1%' or Provider like 'X2%';
```

But it did not return what I need. It only provides the details of X1 as follows,

```
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| Date       | Provider    | sum(Total_Usage) |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| 2022-01-11 | X1_IC_03    |            71.33 |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
```

The provider name also not as requested. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the where clause in() like this (Provider like 'X1%' or Provider like 'X2%')?

Comment: No. I didnt try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by is the right option for you. But you need to be careful. You can have different date values (in your case it's the same). In this case the script doesn't know which date to take. I used max, because you have only one value.

```
select 
    max(Date), LEFT(provider,LOCATE('_',provider) - 1), sum(Total_Usage) 
from 
    Daily_Usage 
group by  LEFT(provider,LOCATE('_',provider) - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. What should change if I had different dates? Normally the Daily_Usage table updates every day.

Comment: If it updated every day and you put current_timestamp in it, then you have a solution. You don't need to change anything.

Comment: Great. This database updates every day and the date is the yesterday value. Then this query provides different sets of sums of each day?   -@XraySensei

Comment: Exactly and the date will always be the latest.